# How do i pass a default value for my @viewbag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a input text box

```
<input class="foo" id="NUM" type="text" value=@ViewBag.Quantity  name="Quan" />
```

And when the userform loads i want it to be set to a default value.

I presume i need to put something in my controller...

Comment: _I presume ..._ You need to set value

Comment: If there are spaces or encoded characters in the value of `@ViewBag.Quantity` then you'll need to wrap it in quotes: `value="@ViewBag.Quantity"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default value by checking if ViewBag is null set some value this way:

```
<input class="foo" id="NUM" type="text" value='@(ViewBag.Quantity == null ? 0 : ViewBag.Quantity)'  name="Quan" />
```

and your current html is invalid which can cause trouble, you are missing quotes of value attribute:

```
<input class="foo" id="NUM" type="text" value="@ViewBag.Quantity"  name="Quan" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what's your controller name? 
I suppose you have one called "ProductsController" that show your view calling the action "AddProduct" like in the example below:

```
class ProductsController : Controller {
    public ActionResult AddProduct() {
        ViewBag.Quantity = 0; // Set default quantity.
        return View();
    }
}
```

You just need to set ViewBag.Quantity value in your controller's action.

Comment: No, if you set ViewBag.Quantity = 10 you will se 10 in your form.